# Node Postgres Docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I try to set up Docker with my node.js app which uses sequelize to connect to postgres.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME,
    process.env.DB_USER,
    process.env.DB_PASS,
    {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres',
    },
);
```

In my `.env` file I declare
`DB_HOST=postgres` (which is the name of the service declared in the docker-conpose.yml) and `DB_PORT=5432` among all the other environment variables.

My `Dockerfile` looks as follows:

```
FROM node:8.6.0

# Working directory for application
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
COPY . /usr/src/app

# In this file I create a user and a DB and give him the privlages 
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN npm install
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` looks as follows:

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.4"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
  node:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: ["npm", "start"]
```

When I `docker-compose up` I get the error that the Sequelize is not able to connect to the DB.

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:5431

Can someone help me with this error?

all the docker logs:

> WARNING: Image for service node was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
>
> Creating graphqlpostgrestemplate_postgres_1 ...
>
> Creating graphqlpostgrestemplate_postgres_1 ... done
>
> Creating graphqlpostgrestemplate_node_1 ...
>
> Creating graphqlpostgrestemplate_node_1 ... done
>
> Attaching to graphqlpostgrestemplate_postgres_1, graphqlpostgrestemplate_node_1
>
> postgres_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
>
> postgres_1  | This user must also own the server process.
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
>
> postgres_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
>
> postgres_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
>
> postgres_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
>
> postgres_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
>
> postgres_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | initializing pg_authid ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | initializing dependencies ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating system views ... ok
>
> node_1      | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> node_1      | npm info using npm@5.3.0
>
> node_1      | npm info using node@v8.6.0
>
> postgres_1  | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
>
> node_1      | npm info lifecycle graphql-postgres-template@1.0.0~prestart: graphql-postgres-template@1.0.0
>
> node_1      | npm info lifecycle graphql-postgres-template@1.0.0~start: graphql-postgres-template@1.0.0
>
> node_1      |
>
> node_1      | > graphql-postgres-template@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
>
> node_1      | > nodemon --exec babel-node index.js
>
> node_1      |
>
> postgres_1  | creating collations ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating conversions ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating dictionaries ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | creating information schema ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
>
> node_1      | [nodemon] 1.12.1
>
> node_1      | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>
> node_1      | [nodemon] watching: *.*
>
> node_1      | [nodemon] starting `babel-node index.js`
>
> postgres_1  | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
>
> postgres_1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  |     postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
>
> postgres_1  | or
>
> postgres_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
>
> postgres_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
>
> postgres_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
>
> postgres_1  | ****************************************************
>
> postgres_1  | WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
>
> postgres_1  |          This will allow anyone with access to the
>
> postgres_1  |          Postgres port to access your database. In
>
> postgres_1  |          Docker's default configuration, this is
>
> postgres_1  |          effectively any other container on the same
>
> postgres_1  |          system.
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  |          Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
>
> postgres_1  |          it in "docker run".
>
> postgres_1  | ****************************************************
>
> postgres_1  | waiting for server to start....LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Cannot assign requested address
>
> postgres_1  | HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-10 12:17:15 UTC
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
>
> postgres_1  |  done
>
> postgres_1  | server started
>
> postgres_1  | ALTER ROLE
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  received fast shutdown request
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  shutting down
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is shut down
>
> node_1      | Tue, 10 Oct 2017 12:17:16 GMT sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators at node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236:13
>
> node_1      | WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/usr/src/app/config
>
> node_1      | WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
>
> node_1      | Tue, 10 Oct 2017 12:17:17 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option at index.js:53:30
>
> node_1      | Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:5431
>
> node_1      |     at connection.connect.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:96:24)
>
> node_1      |     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:123:14)
>
> node_1      |     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>
> node_1      |     at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
>
> node_1      |     at Socket. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
>
> node_1      |     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>
> node_1      |     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
>
> node_1      |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>
> node_1      |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>
> node_1      |     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
>
> node_1      | [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
>
> postgres_1  |  done
>
> postgres_1  | server stopped
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
>
> postgres_1  |
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-10 12:17:16 UTC
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

Comment: could you post your docker logs please?

Answer (score 1):

To your `Docker-compose` add `link` configuration option in your service `node` point to service `postgres` something like this:

```
node:
  links:
    - postgres
```

Then you can connect to `postgresdb` point with name service **postgres**

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. After updating the docker-compose file I get a new Sequelize error.
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:5431
node_1      |     at connection.connect.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:96:24)
node_1      |     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:123:14)
node_1      |     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
node_1      |     at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
node_1      |     at Socket.<anonymous>

Comment: Make sure that ```process.env.DB_HOST``` has set up service ```postgres``` as value.